# Post calls failing in SSO configuration with Wildfly 14.0.1 and PicketLink 2.5.5.SP12

Tags: wildfly, picketlink

I have SSO configuration enabled using PicketLink. It was working fine with Wildfly 10. But after upgrading to Wildfly 14, getting this error.

When we try to login to our application, it gets redirected to IDP and after successful authentication, it comes back to our application.

But here all POST calls are failing with the error:

EOFException : No content to map to Object due to end of input.

As per the stacktrace, this exception is coming in ObjectMapper.java file in jackson-mapper-asl jar.